# React Typescript Jest Call Function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jestjs

I have this component I am trying to test but no matter what I try I am getting errors:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useUser} from '.';

/**
 * Check If the company is locked
 */
export const useIsCompanyLocked = (): boolean => {
  const userInfo = useUser();
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      return;
    }

    (async (): Promise<void> => {
      setStatus(false);
      // Do some stuff
      setStatus('do some condition which returns a boolean result');
    })();
  }, [userInfo, status]);

  return status;
};
```

And here is my jest test which fails:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
import {useIsCompanyLocked} from '../useIsCompanyLocked';
import {mockUseUser} from '@myTest/test-utilities';
import React from 'react';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const appUtils = require('@myTest/app-utilities');

describe('useUserHasSecurityPermissionForCompany', () => {
  const setStatus = jest.fn();
  let useStateSpy: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState');
    useStateSpy.mockImplementation((initialState: any) => [initialState, setStatus]);
  });

  it('should return "false" if user is Admin', () => {
    let mockUser = mockUseUser();
    mockUser = {
      ...mockUser,
      isAdmin: true
      ]
    };
    jest.spyOn(appUtils, 'useUser').mockReturnValue(mockUser);
    const obj = useIsCompanyLocked();
    expect(obj).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

I have tried many different iterations of this test but I always end up with some error. What is the correct way to test this function 'useIsCompanyLocked'?

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Summary of all failing tests
FAIL src/hooks/__tests__/useIsCompanyLocked.test.tsx (10.631s)
  ● useIsCompanyLocked › should return "false" if user is Admin

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: false
    Received: [false, [Function mockConstructor]]

      39 |     jest.spyOn(appUtils, 'useUser').mockReturnValue(mockUser);
      40 |     const obj = useIsCompanyLocked();
    > 41 |     expect(obj).toEqual(false);
         |                 ^
      42 |   });
      43 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/hooks/__tests__/useIsCompanyLocked.test.tsx:41:17)
```

Comment: What sort of issues or errors do you have? I'm going to guess it's something about breaking the rules of hooks since you are trying to call a React hook directly, outside any React component or custom React hook. Can you [edit] to clarify the exact/specific issue/problem you have, include the complete error message(s) and any accompanying error stacktrace(s), and if there's more relevant code, a complete [mcve]?

Comment: Like above comment said, you can't test your hook by calling it directly. I think you need to use additional testing tools, like [renderhook](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#renderhook) from [react-hooks-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library).

Comment: @DrewReese yes it is breaking the rules of hooks. How can I test a hook correctly?

Comment: @het this is a large company project I am trying not to have to add a new library or testing tool. I am unable to find an example in our existing library of someone testing a hook but there is a requirement for me to add testing since I am adding this new hook.

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited my question to include my latest error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that your unit test code is calling a React hook directly instead of within a React component or custom React hook.

## Solution

The common method of unit testing React hooks is to use the [React-Hooks-Testing-Library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library)'s `renderHook` utility. Chances are you are already using [React-Testing-Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) (*if you are not you really ought to consider using it as it's the standard testing library for React UI*), which has the React hooks testing library included.

See [`renderHook`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#renderhook) for details.

Basic Example Usage:

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
import React from 'react';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';
import { mockUseUser } from '@myTest/test-utilities';
import { useIsCompanyLocked } from '../useIsCompanyLocked';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const appUtils = require('@myTest/app-utilities');

describe('useUserHasSecurityPermissionForCompany', () => {
  it('should return "false" if user is Admin', async () => {
    // Prime useUser hook to return user with "isAdmin: true"
    const mockUser = mockUseUser();
    mockUser.isAdmin = true;
    jest.spyOn(appUtils, 'useUser').mockReturnValue(mockUser);

    const { result } renderHook(() => useIsCompanyLocked());

    expect(result.current).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

An additional wrinkle for testing your `useIsCompanyLocked` hook is the asynchronous logic in the `useEffect` hook that updates the `status` state that you actually want to assert on. For this you'll want to mock *that* logic and use the [`act`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#act) utility to "resolve" it and trigger a "rerender" so the test can access the `status` state ***after*** the effect's asynchronous logic has updated the state with the result of the mocked user object.

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
import React from 'react';
import { act, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';
import { mockUseUser } from '@myTest/test-utilities';
import { useIsCompanyLocked } from '../useIsCompanyLocked';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const appUtils = require('@myTest/app-utilities');

describe('useUserHasSecurityPermissionForCompany', () => {
  it('should return "false" if user is Admin', async () => {
    // Setup/mock the asynchronous logic
    const resolvedPromise = Promise.resolve(/* whatever the logic needs in the hook */);
    // any additional mocks, e.g. `fetch` or `axios`, etc

    // Prime useUser hook to return user with "isAdmin: true"
    const mockUser = mockUseUser();
    mockUser.isAdmin = true;
    jest.spyOn(appUtils, 'useUser').mockReturnValue(mockUser);

    const { result } renderHook(() => useIsCompanyLocked());

    // wait for the asynchronous logic to complete
    await act(() => resolvedPromise);

    expect(result.current).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```